# Type inference for type arguments of generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, types, methods, inference

I'm a newby to Stack Overflow so please go easy on me!  I'm reading C# in Depth but I've come across a scenario that I don't believe is covered.  A quick search of the web didn't throw up any results either.

Say I define the following overloaded methods:

```
void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual)

void AreEqual(object expected, object actual)
```

If I call `AreEqual()` without specifying a type argument:

```
AreEqual("Hello", "Hello")
```

Is the generic or non-generic version of the method invoked?  Is the generic method invoked with the type argument being inferred, or is the non-generic method invoked with the method arguments being implicitly cast to `System.Object`?

I hope my question is clear.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: you could of course write some simple code to check this...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - true, but then I wouldn't have got to make my first post.  And its useful for others to see the answer here.

Comment: @Michael Edenfield - well spotted, I've heard good things about Eric Lippert's blog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generics can generate a function `AreEqual(string, string)`. This is a closer match than `AreEqual(object, object)`, so therefore the generic function is chosen.

Interestingly, the compiler will choose this generic function even if it results in a constraint violation error.

Look at this example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleSandbox
{
    interface IBar
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Foo<T>(T obj1) where T: IBar
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Inside Foo<T>");
        }


        static void Foo(object obj)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Inside Foo Object");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Foo("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Even HERE it will choose the generic version over the non-generic version. And then you get this error:

> The type 'string' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic
>   type or method 'ConsoleSandbox.Program.Foo(T)'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'string' to 'ConsoleSandbox.IBar'.

But if you add a function `Foo(string obj1)` it will work.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  Nice example, I tried it myself just to confirm :-)

Comment: Note that overload resolution is done by the C# compiler, not the .NET framework.